# displaying mysql timestamp correctly

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Hey i'm trying to display a date/time from a timestamp field using:

```
echo $date = date( "D F j", $row['date'] );
```

However it returns: Wed December 3
When it should return today: Monday July 13

Timestamp from the DB row is: `2009-07-13 04:16:31`

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) AS `date` FROM ...
```

This will give you the date in the correct format to pass in to PHP's [`date()`](http://php.net/date) function.

Edit:

```
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) AS `date` FROM songs WHERE date >= DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 2 WEEK )
```

As a side note - it's best to avoid using NOW() in queries as it prevents them being cached - inject the date in you application instead.

Comment: Erm... How would I integrate that into my SELECT * query:  SELECT * FROM songs WHERE date >= DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 2 WEEK )

Comment: Thanks on the NOW() I will change it.

Comment: How would you write that query without NOW()?

Comment: Put the date in the query in your app: DATE_SUB('2009-07-13', INTERVAL 2 WEEK)

Comment: Could you do time(); also or $now = $time(); or $now = date(); and then: DATE_SUB( $now , INTERVAL 2 WEEK)  ?

Comment: mysql_query('SELECT ... DATE_SUB("' . date('Y-m-d') . '", INTERVAL 2 WEEK) ...');

Answer (score 1):

Also possible:

```
$date = date( "D F j", strtotime( $row['date'] ) );
```

But Greg's solution is better coding.

Comment: Ahhh. That looks familiar. I could not remember how I did it before. Thanks for the alternate method.